# How to use qcut/cut methods in polars

Tags: rust, rust-polars

there is the method [`qcut`/`cut` in Polars-Python](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/series/api/polars.Series.qcut.html#polars.Series.qcut) implementation.

But no documentation about this function in Polars-Rust documentation.

Is it possible to use this function in Polars-Rust?

I want to group by my `DataFrame` by specific intervals.

Comment: Those functions are explicitly listed as unstable on the documentation page you provided.